Are the sum of Characteristic kernels also Characteristic?
I'm trying to understand what characteristic kernels are. I have a PD kernel $K$ that is a sum of radial kernels. I want to use a function (basically the kernel $K$ itself) derived from the RKHS (Reproducing kernel Hilbert Space) of this kernel $K$ within MMD (Maximum Mean Discrepancy) [1]. I understand that radial kernels are universal and characteristic [2]. I also understand that sum of PD kernels are also PD. But are sum of characteristic kernels also characteristic? How do I go about showing this? Thank you so much!
[1] https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v13/gretton12a.html
[2] https://jmlr.org/papers/volume12/sriperumbudur11a/sriperumbudur11a.pdf

I found this question very helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276497/maximum-mean-discrepancy-distance-distribution
